# How to create meeting using RubyOutlook gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, office365api

I am new here using ruby and outlook and found the gem RubyOutlook which is wrapper around office365 and ruby

How do i create a meeting request using RubyOutlook gem and do we have any help file for doing it

Answer (score 1):

The gem's [readme](https://github.com/jasonjoh/ruby_outlook) is scarce, so you have to look in the [source code](https://github.com/jasonjoh/ruby_outlook/blob/master/lib/ruby_outlook.rb). 
After creating an oauth token, as described in the readme, you need to call `create_event` with the token, event json payload, calendar folder (nil for default calendar) and the email of the user who would be the owner of the event:

```
require 'ruby_outlook'
outlook_client = RubyOutlook::Client.new
# ...
# create oauth token, as described in the readme
# ...
event_payload = 
{
  "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": {
      "DateTime": "2014-02-02T18:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "End": {
      "DateTime": "2014-02-02T19:00:00",
      "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "john@example.com",
        "Name": "John Doe"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
outlook_client.create_event(token, event_payload, nil, 'john@example.com')
```

[Here's the relevant Outlook API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#CreateAnEvent) for creating events. This is where I took the event payload.